# Crystal reports group selection sorting

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report

I am working on a report that has two parameters that gives the user the ability to sort the records. One being the salesman and the other being the company code which is just the first three letters of the company name. They want the ability to sort these records upon running the report and this is the code I have so far

```
(if {?customer num} = "<ALL>" then true else {AR_OpenInvoice.CustomerNo} = {?customer num} and 
if {?SmanFilter} = "<ALL>" then true else {AR_OpenInvoice.SalespersonNo} = {?SmanFilter})
```

When the report is ran if you select an option for salesman AND the company code (xxx - xxx company code) it works perfectly. However, if you do  companies and sort by salesman it returns ALL salesman and not just that salesman. I am stumped on this one and any guidance would be great.

Comment: Just a side note. If I run the report with <ALL> salesman and different companies the report returns just those companies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean filtering. I have had some experiences of `if` clauses not working correctly in filters. Use `or` instead:

```
({?customer num} = "<ALL>" or {AR_OpenInvoice.CustomerNo} = {?customer num})
and 
({?SmanFilter} = "<ALL>" or {AR_OpenInvoice.SalespersonNo} = {?SmanFilter})
```

Comment: OK so instead of the AND in the formula use OR?

Comment: No, replace the formula you provided with the formula in my answer. I replaced the `if-then-else` statements with `or`. If it still doesn't work there's something wrong with the parameters or something else that doesn't show in the info in the question.